# Confusion in word order for a complex sentence - Subjunctive explanation

Tags: sentence-structure

I was reading a sentence for the subjunctive when learning in German -

> Der Konjunktiv II des Verbs sein wird gebildet, indem man in der Vergangenheitsform den Vokal im Stamm durch einen Umlaut ersetzt. Allerdings wird bei den Formen ich und er/sie/es noch die Endung -e angefügt:

Now, I want to break this sentence down individually.

I see the first sentence is a passive sentence (werden + past participle):

> Der Konjunktiv II des Verbs sein wird gebildet

which I translate to be

> The Subjunctive II of the verb "sein" are formed

but the next part is confusing in the word order.

> indem man in der Vergangenheitsform den Vokal im Stamm durch einen Umlaut ersetzt.

I know the verb I'm looking for is **ersetzt** (ersetzen = to replace) but I can't identify in what tense this verb is being used.

Also, beyond that, I seem to work out the sentence translates roughly as:

> by replacing in the past tense, the vowel in the stem with an Umlaut.

My question is **what tense is ersetzt being used in?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"Ersetzt"* is in the present tense here. Take the part of the sentence you are having trouble with:

> ... indem man in der Vergangenheitsform den Vokal im Stamm durch einen Umlaut ersetzt

Because it's a subordinate clause the verb goes to the end of the clause. You can rewrite the relevant part as

> man ersetzt den Vokal im Stamm durch einen Umlaut

and as you can see, it's present tense

Comment: does the "indem" push the ersetzt to the end of the sentence, similar to a "weil"?

Comment: yes it's the same idea

Comment: similar to any conjunction for a subordinate clause ("weil", "falls", "bevor", "obwohl", "damit", "dass", ...) as well as relative clauses